# How to work around force-pushing of an upstream branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-push, git-rewrite-history

I have a feature branch `branchX` that is using `some-remote/base-branch` as its upstream branch. I just discovered that `some-remote/base-branch` got its history rewritten by a force-push. What are the problems involved and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 8):

The biggest problem that this brings is that you *should* get rid of the revisions that were rewritten from the old upstream branch so that when you push your feature branch, they are no longer there.

If you tried rebasing your branch on top of the new branch (say, `git checkout branchX; git fetch some-remote; git rebase some-remote/base-branch`) git will not only rebase the revisions of your feature branch *but* also the revisions that have already been moved out of the new rewritten branch... which is a **no go**. Same thing if merging. So a simple `git pull` (merging or rebasing) won't get you out of the mess... actually, you might very well dig yourself **deeper** into the mess.

If you decided to keep them *as if nothing happened*, you will get into the history of the *new* upstream branch, revisions that have already been removed from it and, *more than likely*, there is no need to keep them (because.... why was the history of the branch rewritten in the first place, right? If it was rewritten, those old revisions are not to be seen anymore).

It might seem like it is a **big deal**, but quite frankly, it is not that hard to get out of the situation. The trick is to move *only* revisions of your feature branch on top of the new rewritten branch leaving behind the old branch. So, this is the procedure, assuming that the branch for your feature is a straight line with no merges:

## The Pledge

Find out in the history of *your* feature branch (say, with `git log` or `gitk` or any other means necessary), the last revision from the **old** upstream branch that is in your feature branch. Say you get the ID of that revision and let's call it `old-base-rev`.

Fetch from the remote to get the new rewritten history of the upstream branch.

```
git fetch some-remote # adjust to the name of your remote, of course
```

## The Turn

This is where the magic happens:

```
git rebase --onto some-remote/base-branch old-base-rev branchX
```

This way git will only rebase the revisions that actually make up the work on the feature branch itself and not the old upstream branch.

## The Prestige

And that's it. You are free to continue working on your branch as if nothing happened.

## Other possibilities

If you are dealing with a feature branch that is *not* straight (it has had merges of the upstream branch instead of rebasing it), you might use the same recipe I provided, however, if you had to solve conflicts when merging the upstream branch, that will be tricky. If you want to avoid having to deal with the conflicts again, perhaps the best you could try is to get your changes for your feature branch into a single revision and then attempt the magic trick. After having found what the last ID of the *old* base branch is in your feature branch:

```
git reset --soft old-base-rev
git commit -m "Single revision for feature X"
```

Now all your changes have been collapsed into a single revision on top of `old-base-rev`. Then you can follow the recipe with the fetch/rebase steps.

```
git fetch some-remote
git rebase --onto some-remote/base-branch old-base-rev branchX
```

Comment: This kind of trick is also useful when you have a feature branch that is built on top of another feature branch. The feature branch that you used as your base might be rebased/rewritten/reborn/whatever and so you don't want to move around those revisions that do not belong to your feature branch when you move your branch around.